# Replicating stata results in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, stata, ordered-logit

I'm working with a faculty member who wanted me to do the data work in Stata, but now wants me to estimate the models in R as well because the graphics are more flexible. However, I'm having some trouble satisfactorily replicating in R (using Zelig) the ordered logit results I was getting in stata.

Here's my stata code + some coefficients:

```
ologit usworld_strength teaparty libcpre_self tp_ideo presapp_job_x ethno gender_respondent_x dem_age_r_x profile_hhincome white profile_educ south1 fox

teaparty         -.1643072
pid_x            -.0533524  
libcpre_self     -.0446034  
presapp_job_x     .6730102  
gender_respo~x   -.1781718  
dem_age_r_x      -.0059065
profile_hhin~e   -.0054595  
white            -.2540782 
profile_educ     -.0067142      
south1            .1418142 
fox              -.4316206
```

---

In R, here's my code. Note that many of these independent variables are categorical. The only way I've been able to get the model to run was with `as.numeric` in front of these. `as.factor` produces the error:

```
Warning message:
In polr(formula = as.factor(usworld_strength) ~ teaparty + as.factor(pid_x) +  :
  design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs

usstr.out <- zelig(usworld_strength ~ teaparty + as.numeric(pid_x) + 
                                      as.numeric(libcpre_self) + 
                                      as.numeric(presapp_job_x) + ethno + 
                                      gender_respondent_x + dem_age_r_x + 
                                      as.numeric(profile_hhincome) + white + 
                                      as.numeric(profile_educ) + south1 + fox, 
                   model = "ologit", data = dta)
summary(usstr.out)
```

Note that the output in R differs from that in Stata, in particular for all of the categorical independent variables. Clearly, this is where the funny business is happening, but I'm unclear about what I'm doing wrong.

```
Coefficients:
                                 Value 
teaparty                     -0.162995  
as.numeric(pid_x)            -0.045954   
as.numeric(libcpre_self)     -0.045149 
as.numeric(presapp_job_x)     0.957340 
gender_respondent_x2. female -0.178955 
dem_age_r_x                  -0.005982   
as.numeric(profile_hhincome) -0.004508  
white                        -0.221815  
as.numeric(profile_educ)     -0.001753  
south1                        0.141999  
fox                          -0.415817
```

Comment: This is not a bad question, but probably belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: If your categorical variables have more than 2 levels, `as.numeric()` will get you into a lot of trouble; you will get only a single coefficient for each variable,and its value will depend on the ordering of the levels. The warning about rank-deficiency suggests that you have some predictors that are exactly linearly related to each other (or that there is some problem in data coding). Examine the data carefully with this in mind, and see if Stata perhaps also dropped some coefficients without warning you.

Comment: This question would be closed on SO because it doesn't have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536). There is an overview of the different ways of running an OLR in R [here](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/regressionOrdinal.html).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use software without a reproducible example.

Comment: Not really sure how to give you guys a reproducible example, because the problem is with this particular dataset. Short of giving you the dataset, I'm not sure I can reproduce the problem for you (I'm happy to do this). I'm more interested in any feedback on how to deal with the as.numeric problem. Basically, stata is giving me one coefficient for each of the categorical IV's, whereas R will either give me one coefficient for every level, or, if I use as.numeric, will give me one overall coefficient that doesn't match the stata coefficient.

Comment: In Stata, you might try `i.x` where you use `as.factor(x)`.

Comment: Please use 4 space or the code `{` selection to format computer code and output for readability.

Comment: This question appears to be about ways of encoding categorical variables for regression models and as such qualifies to stay here on CV. Without having access to the data, though, we cannot be expected to diagnose the specific problem that is described.

Comment: Write some R code (with set.seed) that simulates some data, uses it to estimate a toy model similar to yours, and writes the simulated data to csv. Then read that csv into stata and see whether you get the same results. Try and reproduce the difference between stata and R that way, and then post the simulation + estimation R code here.

Comment: Post the exact Stata syntax and exact Stata output, as well as exact R syntax and exact R output. If R complains about the design matrix not being a full rank, then Stata may have gone a step further and dropped some collinear variables to get any work done. So you may want to check that the estimation samples are actually the same; if you end up with 180 cases in one package and with 185 cases in another, then it would be pretty difficult to get identical results.